# Hive meta store in docker

Tags: docker, hive, hive-metastore

I want run `hive metastore` with `docker` in `debian`.

The version of `hive` is `3.1.3` and `hadoop` is `3.3.5`.

it can create database and tables of `metasore` in `MySQL`, but it accrue this error:

```
2023-04-01 11:36:13: Starting Metastore Server
hive-metastore  | SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
hive-metastore  | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/apache-hive-metastore-3.1.3-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
hive-metastore  | SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/opt/hadoop-3.3.5/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-reload4j-1.7.36.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
hive-metastore  | SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
hive-metastore  | SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
hive-metastore  | 2023-04-01 11:36:21,833 main INFO Log4j appears to be running in a Servlet environment, but there's no log4j-web module available. If you want better web container support, please add the log4j-web JAR to your web archive or server lib directory.
hive-metastore  | MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MaterializationsCacheCleanerTask class not found)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:93)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8672)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8667)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:8937)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:8854)
hive-metastore  |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
hive-metastore  |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
hive-metastore  |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
hive-metastore  |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:328)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:241)
hive-metastore  | Caused by: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MaterializationsCacheCleanerTask class not found)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.utils.JavaUtils.getClass(JavaUtils.java:54)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:589)
hive-metastore  |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
hive-metastore  |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
hive-metastore  |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
hive-metastore  |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:147)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:108)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:80)
hive-metastore  |       ... 11 more
hive-metastore  | Exception in thread "main" MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MaterializationsCacheCleanerTask class not found)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:84)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:93)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8672)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:8667)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.startMetaStore(HiveMetaStore.java:8937)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.main(HiveMetaStore.java:8854)
hive-metastore  |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
hive-metastore  |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
hive-metastore  |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
hive-metastore  |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:328)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:241)
hive-metastore  | Caused by: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MaterializationsCacheCleanerTask class not found)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.utils.JavaUtils.getClass(JavaUtils.java:54)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:589)
hive-metastore  |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
hive-metastore  |       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
hive-metastore  |       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
hive-metastore  |       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invokeInternal(RetryingHMSHandler.java:147)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.invoke(RetryingHMSHandler.java:108)
hive-metastore  |       at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:80)
hive-metastore  |       ... 11 more
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 25 [Warning] Aborted connection 25 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 20 [Warning] Aborted connection 20 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 18 [Warning] Aborted connection 18 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 24 [Warning] Aborted connection 24 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 15 [Warning] Aborted connection 15 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 14 [Warning] Aborted connection 14 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 13 [Warning] Aborted connection 13 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 21 [Warning] Aborted connection 21 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 16 [Warning] Aborted connection 16 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 12 [Warning] Aborted connection 12 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 10 [Warning] Aborted connection 10 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 19 [Warning] Aborted connection 19 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 8 [Warning] Aborted connection 8 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 23 [Warning] Aborted connection 23 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 6 [Warning] Aborted connection 6 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 9 [Warning] Aborted connection 9 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 22 [Warning] Aborted connection 22 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 7 [Warning] Aborted connection 7 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 17 [Warning] Aborted connection 17 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
mariadb         | 2023-04-01 11:36:35 11 [Warning] Aborted connection 11 to db: 'metastore_db' user: 'admin' host: '192.168.80.4' (Got an error reading communication packets)
```

what is this error and how can solve that?

Comment: Look to see if `MaterializationsCacheCleanerTask` exists in the metastore version that you have installed or has been deprecated/removed in some way.

Comment: Facing the exact same issue, ever figured this out Tavakoli?

Answer (score 2):

My solution to this was to edit the `metastore-site.xml`

From this

```xml
    <property>
        <name>metastore.task.threads.always</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.events.EventCleanerTask,org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MaterializationsCacheCleanerTask</value>
    </property>
```

to

```
    <property>
        <name>metastore.task.threads.always</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.events.EventCleanerTask</value>
    </property>
```

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks!

I'm guessing that was leftover from an older config template.